# PHPExcel generates 500 error on save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpexcel

I've just uploaded a set of code from my development server to my live one, and PHPExcel has started just generating a 500 error when i try to save anything. the code is below
(Note: this all worked fine on the dev server, and both PHPExcel and Laravel work fine when transitioning between the two for other applications)

```
$PHPExcel = new PHPExcel;

$filename = 'Companies_Export_'.Session::getId().'.xls';
$file = public_path().'/_assets/exports/'.$filename;

//$fp = fopen($file, 'w');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save($file);
```

I've removed the code to populate the file, in case it was a filesize issue.

I've used fopen to test if the application has write access to the directory, and that creates a new file with the correct name in the correct place, so that's fine too.

I've tried changing the file name to just '1.xls' so it's not an issue with Session::getId()

If i comment out the $objWriter->save($file); line, it all works fine, just obviously doesn't save, and if i put garbage in as the parameter instead of a legitimate directory/filename, it still just 500's, so indicating PHPExcel must be failing while compiling the file or something?

I'm at a loss now, no matter what i do it won't show me an error, it just throws a 500 page with no info (detailed error page just says php fastcgi process exited unexpectedly or similar)

Info:
PHP version 5.3.10
Windows Server 2008
IIS 7.5

Comment: When you open the file for writing, and then `PHPExcel` tries to write the file, it might be locked. Please don't let us guess the problem and lookup the exact error from the log files.

Comment: laravel.log contains no information on the particular error

Comment: laravel log? Look in PHP error log. With fpm on debian it's in `/var/log/php5-fpm.log`, with apache it's in `/var/log/httpd/error.log` or `/var/log/apache/error.log` etc

Comment: php-errors.log is also blank - checked php_info and errors are on and logged to that particular file

Comment: My `error_log` variable in phpinfo is empty. But in `/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` it is configured to `error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log` (which is actually working). Note: `; If it's set to "syslog", log is sent to syslogd instead of being written in a local file.`, it can also be virtual host specific and in `/var/www/vhosts/xxx.domain.com/log/error.log`. Check other log files too, like `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Can you try please to force an error (`<?php include('non-existent-file');` and see if that appears in your `php-errors.log`?

Comment: changed it to be using syslog instead, so the logged error is:

Faulting application name: php-cgi.exe, version: 5.3.10.0, time stamp: 0x4f2ae019
Faulting module name: php5.dll, version: 5.3.10.0, time stamp: 0x4f2ae082
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00091818
Faulting process id: 0x17cc
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfafd2bd36811f
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP5310\php-cgi.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP5310\php5.dll
Report Id: 08be4c4f-1bc7-11e4-a09c-001cc4e2ea5c

Comment: Uff windows with oldschool PHP version :D Sorry, cannot help any further.

Comment: I think it's a windows+php problem, combination of command lead to those errors. ["I updatet my php form 5.3.10 to 5.3.12 and problem was solved."](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=41893&p=133633) (searched for 'Fault offset: 0x00091818').

Comment: just about to do that yeah, do you want to put that up as an answer so i can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Hey Ben, is it actually working with the upgraded version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason we don't get a useful error message is because PHP (`process exited unexpectedly`) itself crashes before beeing able to drop a note on the reason for its crash. Thus it can hardly be solved by PHP scripting due to PHP internal error.

I am kinda certain that an upgrade to a newer PHP version will solve the issues.